# You MUST give notice

Tags: united-states, employment-agreement

Since almost every state in the US is a Right to Work state, why do company employment agreements always say you *must* or are *required* to give X number of weeks notice before leaving a company?  "Must/required" denotes mandatory.  Due to the Right to Work laws in the US, one can leave a job at any time, giving notice or not.

Is there a reason for this strong wording, even if it is not legally binding?

Comment: What gave you the idea it isn't legally binding?  They can't make you work, true, but that doesn't mean there are no consequences.

Comment: @Nelson "What gave you the idea it isn't legally binding?" Mostly due to the fact it isnt legally binding.

Comment: @Keltari Have you verified that with a lawyer in your state with your contract?  I would absolutely be doing that before I claimed certainty that it isn't legally binding.

Comment: @JaneS As a matter of fact, yes.  I was told, this state is, as almost every other US state is, a Right to Work state.  The Right to Work, clearly states you can leave or be relieved of work at any time.  But Im sure you are well aware of that, as I believe you have answered/commented on RTW questions and answers before.  I am curious as to why you would ignore this.

Comment: @Keltari I am not US based, so it's highly unlikely that I have answered questions on Right to Work.  The simple fact is that if you are sure, why are you asking the question on Stack Exchange?  If you have employed a lawyer to confirmed _your specific contract_, then you already have your answer which would make your asking here rather moot.  If you haven't confirmed _your specific contract_, you are still basing on hearsay and aren't completely convinced.

Comment: @JaneS My mistake, I assumed you were US based.  However, this absolutely does not answer the question.  It is part, if not entirely,  the reason why it is unenforceable.  I have added that to the question.

Comment: @Keltari From what I can read, your "right to work" laws (which do NOT exist in "most" states, but exactly half of them) are mostly concerning unions (eg. not allowed to only hire union members, etc.) ... We don't even know in which state you are. How can we possibly help you? And if the only thing your lawyer told you is that this law exists, this statement is worthless for your problem here.

Comment: @Keltari "It is part, if not entirely, the reason why it is unenforceable."  Were you told this in consultation with a lawyer with respect to your specific contract and circumstances?  If not, then it is still a guess and one that can have some serious consequences if you breach contractual obligations based on what you _think_ it is rather than advice from legal counsel.  You still haven't answered my question if you have consulted a lawyer about your specific circumstances :)

Comment: Are you an attorney?  What is your basis for a contract is not legally binding?

Comment: @paparazzo no employment contract can supersede anything proscribed or prescribed by law.  Any HR wonk knows that.

Comment: Are you confusing Right to Work with At-Will?

Comment: If you don't have an employment contract you have to make that explicit in your question; otherwise people will assume you have one.

Answer (score 7):

You are conflating "right-to-work" and "at-will".

Right-to-work means that you can't be forced to join a union in order to get a job.

At-will means that the employer can let you go for any reasons as long as it isn't for a discriminatory reason. It also means the employee can quit at any time.

But if you sign an agreement, also known as a contract, then these rights change. What they have to pay you if they let you go with zero notice, or what you may owe them if you leave without giving proper notice can be addressed in the employment agreement. It can also specify a time period. The agreement is where items such as continuation of benefits, and severance pay are covered. That is also where post-employment issues are addressed.

Comment: With a contract, you can also negotiate terms of it such as asking if they can equally give you a notice period so there's a vice versa. Wouldn't hurt to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Even if there isn't anything to let them legally force you to give/serve out a notice period they can use carrots and sticks to encourage it.

eg if you just say "today's my last day" at 4:59pm and then walk out the door you can forget about getting a good reference from the place in the future.  At my current employer giving 2 weeks notice is a requirement to have any unused vacation days paid out.